# My Snakemake code is deleting the source directory after moving files

Tags: python, shell, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have a snakemake script which processes samples from a source folder (containing raw data). So in my last rule I have written a code which checks if the final file exist or not, if it exist it should move the main file from the source folder to other folder(folder with the name of sample).
But the thing is after the rule is executed, it automatically deletes the source folder. How can i prevent this.
I have written it in Python code.

```py
rule movingData:
    input:
        file = config["ResultDir"]+"{sample}/Annotation/{sample}_FINAL.csv",
        first = config["SampleDir"]+"{sample}_R1.fastq.gz",
        second = config["SampleDir"]+"{sample}_R2.fastq.gz"
    output:
         temporary(touch(config["ResultDir"]+"{sample}/RawData/file.txt"))
    run:
        if os.path.exists(input.file):
            for sample in rawSAMPLES:
                os.rename(input.first,f'{config["ResultDir"]}{sample}/RawData/{sample}_R1.fastq.gz')
                os.rename(input.second,f'{config["ResultDir"]}{sample}/RawData/{sample}_R2.fastq.gz')
```

Same thing happens when I did it in shell.

```py
rule movingData:
    input:
        file = config["ResultDir"]+"{sample}/Annotation/{sample}_FINAL.csv",
        first = config["SampleDir"]+"{sample}_R1.fastq.gz",
        second = config["SampleDir"]+"{sample}_R2.fastq.gz"
    output:
        temporary(touch(config["ResultDir"]+"{sample}/RawData/file.txt"))
    params: directory(config["ResultDir"]+"{sample}/RawData/")
    shell:
        '''
        [[ -f {input.file} ]] && mv {input.first} {input.second} {params}
        '''
```

Comment: I haven't looked at your code in detail but my first thought is that `temporary` should not be there and it is doing something unexpected. Are you sure you need it?

Comment: Could you post the traceback?

Comment: @dariober actually this rule has no particular output and i wanted something so that i could include it in rule all. Thats why i did that `temporary()`. But even without temporary I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Sorry bro, i dont know how to do that. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @NikhilPanchal: ah, I mean the output of Snakemake in the terminal (it might contain hints on what is happening), especially if you use `snakemake -r` option.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev in terminal its not showing any kind of error.
`Touching output file /home/mnt/WES_Result/MohitPawar/RawData/file.txt.`

`Removing temporary output file /home/mnt/WES_Result/MohitPawar/RawData/file.txt`

`Finished job 0.
2 of 2 steps (100%) done
Complete log: /home/ubuntu/.snakemake/log/2022-02-10T120744.253599.snakemake.log`

These two sentences are printed.

Comment: Your rule does have output, the new file locations.  Have you tried making that explicit?  Also, consider symbolic links instead of moving as otherwise snakemake may think your sample files no longer exist.